# Is this correct usage of brackets?

Tags: square-brackets

Is this the correct use of brackets?

"[To me], this value means to respect your colleagues."

Comment: Well we have no idea why you are putting "to me" in brackets so we have no way of telling you if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

The best time to use brackets in a quotation is when you are replacing what was actually said with a word or phrase that says the same thing in a shortened or condensed manner, or that clarifies something ambiguous or missing from the original quotation.
Your quoted text would be appropriate if, for example, you were quoting me as having said

> in the opinion of myself, Elijah, greatest of all grammarians, this value means to respect your colleagues

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use brackets in journalism to include an omitted Or elided word or phrase or to avoid ambiguity.

"It is stupid."
"[the decision] is stupid."

"Came right out the door!" 
"[John] came right out the door!"